# Which model for data which has within-effects, between effects and non-parallel lines

Tags: spss, repeated-measures, ordinal-data

My data (Panel, 19 countries, 7 years, ordinal outcome variable) has within-effects (countries over time), between effects (between countries) and it seems as if the slope of lines (test of parallel lines) differs between the different outcome categories. How can you estimate the model in SPSS properly?

Comment: Parallel lines assumption seems to be crucial for ordinal logit model. If the assumption is substantially violated, I would 1) try another link function; if it doesn't help, 2) try maybe merging some adjacent categories of the DV. Else, 3) consider the DV as nominal and use multinomial logit model.

Comment: @ttnphns made some good suggestions. For more (and for more detail), see Agresti, [Analysis of Ordinal Categorical Data](http://www.amazon.com/Analysis-Ordinal-Categorical-Probability-Statistics/dp/0470082895/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1380881274&sr=8-1&keywords=analysis+of+ordinal+categorical+data). One model that might help is partial proportional odds.